# How to sum a variable and record the total in the last row using SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset looks like the following:

```
Name   Number
a      1
b      2
c      9
d      6
e      5.5
Total  ???
```

I want to calculate the sum of variable `Number` and record the sum in the last row (corresponding with Name = 'total'). I know I can do this using proc means then merge the output backto this file. But this seems not very efficient. Can anyone tell me whether there is any better way please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do the following in a dataset:

```
data test2;
drop sum;
set test end = last;
retain sum;
if _n_ = 1 then sum = 0;
sum = sum + number;
output;
if last then do;
NAME = 'TOTAL';
number = sum;
output;
end;
run;
```

it takes just one pass through the dataset

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to get by report procedure.

```
data have;
input Name $  Number ;
cards;
a      1
b      2
c      9
d      6
e      5.5
;

proc report data=have out=want(drop=_:);
rbreak after/ summarize ;
  compute after;
     name='Total';
  endcomp;
run;
```

Comment: This is the best one: less code and doesn't depend on column name. So if the table have n numeric columns it computes the total for each one

Answer (score 1):

The following code uses the [DOW-Loop](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2010/BB13.Dorfman.pdf) (DO-Whitlock) to achieve the result by reading through the observations once, outputting each one, then lastly outputting the total:

```
data want(drop=tot);
  do until(lastrec);
    set have end=lastrec;
    tot+number;
    output;
  end;
  
  name='Total';
  number=tot;
  output;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

For all of the data step solutions offered, it is important to keep in mind the 'Length' factor. Make sure it will accommodate both 'Total' and original values.

```
proc sql;
select max(5,length) into :len trimmed from dictionary.columns WHERE LIBNAME='WORK' AND MEMNAME='TEST' AND UPCASE(NAME)='NAME';
QUIT;

data test2;
length name $ &len;
set test end=last;
...
run;
```